# How to auto clear/reset datepicker using on.change function?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I have tried many ways below to clear/reset value for datepicker using `on.(change)` function, but it does not happen. I am using Air Datepicker plugin with Bootstrap 4.

**HTML**

```
<select title="-- NODE --" id="nodes" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple>
    <option value="">-- NODE --</option>
</select>
<input id="date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker-here">
```

**JS** (3 ways)

```
$("#nodes").change(function() {
    $("#date").empty();
});

$("#nodes").change(function() {
    $("#date").val("").datepicker(clear);
});

$("#nodes").change(function() {
    $("#date").data(datepicker).clear()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
$('#nodes').on('change', function() {
    $('#date').val('');
});
```